# Unable to access methods using dynamic polymorphism [JAVA]

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I am trying to solve the following problem[image]

I have made the following hierarchy.

```
public abstract class Employee{

 private String name;
 private Integer id;
 protected Type type;

 Employee(){}

 Employee(String name,Integer id){
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;           
 }

 abstract public void calculatePay();

 protected void benifits(){
    System.out.println("Basic Benifts");
 }

 public void printType(){
    System.out.println(this.type);
 }

}



public class Intern extends Employee{

 Intern(){
    super("default",123);
 }

 Intern(String name,Integer id){
    super(name,id);
    this.type = Type.Intern;
 }

 public void calculatePay(){
    System.out.println("Intern Pay");
 }

}

class Developer extends Employee{

 Developer(){
    super("default",123);
 }

 Developer(String name,Integer id){
    super(name,id);
    this.type = Type.Developer;
 }

 public void calculatePay(){
    System.out.println("Developer Pay");
 }

 protected void benifits(){
    super.benifits();
    System.out.println("Developer Benifits");
 }

}

class Manager extends Developer{

 public Manager(){
    super("default",123);
 }

 public Manager(String name,Integer id){
    super(name,id);
    this.type = Type.Manager;
 }

 public void calculatePay(){
    System.out.println("Manager Pay");
 }

 public void benifits(){
    super.benifits();
    System.out.println("Manger Benifits");
 }

 public void foo(){
    System.out.println("foo");
 }

}
```

And the driver is as follows

```
class Driver{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Employee manager = new Manager("Ali",1);
        manager.calculatePay();
        manager.benifits();     
        manager.printType();

        manager.foo();
    }

}
```

Type is an Enumeration. 
Now the problem is that I can't access foo() method using dynamic approach. But when I do static polymorphism like `Manager manager = new Manager()` I can access it.

What is the particular reason of this behavior. Is my design correct? What would be a better design? And which design pattern should I use?

Comment: Can you edit and write the piece of code that you want as an expectation?

Comment: yes. I understand accessing foo() bit. though what do you think about the design of the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to have the `Type` enum, the class itself (i.e. `Intern`) represents the employee type.

Related to the issue of not being able to call `manager.foo()` is because from a variable of a specific type you can call only those methods which are declared on that type (class).

In your case, when you declare `Employee manager = new Manager("Ali", 1);` you can call methods which are declared on `Employee`, in this case `foo()` is declared on `Manager` class

Answer (score -1):

When you do `Employee manager = new Manager("Ali",1);` even though you are creating a `Manager` instance but the type is `Employee`, since the type is `Employee` the compiler do not know `manager.foo();` is.

So you have to defile a `void foo()` method it can be abstract also.

Comment: I have tried checking datatype as follows.

System.out.println(manager.getClass().getSimpleName()); // gives manager

  if(manager instanceof Manager){
   System.out.println("manager"); //true
  }

  if(manager instanceof Employee){
   System.out.println("Employee"); //true 

  }

Basically, It looks like if leaf class has some unique functionality it is better that I do static polymorphism. Though what do you think about the design?